# how to write exif tags with Python in a self generated image

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, exif, self, generated

I have generated an image with pillow and now I want to add metadata to the image.
In my image it didn't have a data structure yet, I suppose I have to create one first but how do I do that?

Reading or changing tags from existing images with exif data structure is very easy with the "exif" tool.

Every hint is welcome.

Unfortunately, I am somewhat at a loss and have not yet found any useful information on the Internet.

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far and where you are stuck.  Question needs some code
Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

```
from PIL import Image, PngImagePlugin

#path to image file
file = "myimage.png"

#create the metadata object
pngMetaData = PngImagePlugin.PngInfo()

#add the data
pngMetaData.add_text('key 1', 'value 1')
pngMetaData.add_text('key 2', 'value 2')

#open the image file and save the metadata
with Image.open(file) as image_file:
    image_file.save(file, pnginfo=pngMetaData)
```